# Unable to get stacks in d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to know what i am doing wrong i think its in the axis as the stacked data as well as well as the rect elements are showing. Been stuck now for 2 hours.

```js
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 50},
    width = 760 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    innerheight=height + margin.top + margin.bottom


d3.csv("data.csv", function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }

    // var subgroups = data.columns.slice(1);
    // console.log(subgroups);

    
    var subgroups = d3.map(data, function(d){ return(d.Segment)}).keys();

    
    var groups = d3.map(data, function(d){ return(d.Category)}).keys();
    console.log(groups);

// Add X axis
var x = d3.scaleBand()
.domain(groups)
.range([0, width])
.padding([0.2])
svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0));

// Add Y axis
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Sales; })])
.range([ height , 0 ]);
console.log(y.domain())
console.log(y.range())
svg.append("g")
.call(d3.axisLeft(y));

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain(subgroups)
.range(['#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a']);


ymax= d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Sales; });

console.log(subgroups);

var stackedData = d3.stack().keys(subgroups);
stackedData = stackedData(data)
console.log(stackedData);
svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("g")
        // Enter in the stack data = loop key per key = group per group
        .data(stackedData)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("fill", function (d) { return (color(d.key)); })
        .selectAll("rect")
        // enter a second time = loop subgroup per subgroup to add all rectangles
        .data(function (d) { return d; })
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.data.Category); })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return  y(d.data.Sales); })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return  (height - y(d.data.Sales)) ; })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())


});
```

---

csv is in this format

Row ID,Segment,Category,Sales,Total
1,Consumer,Accessories,84754.742,1007859.426
2,Consumer,Appliances,42852.68,1007859.426
31,Corporate,Phones,89019.204,588163.8014
34,Corporate,Tables,57226.0385,588163.8014
37,Home Office,Art,4799.502,373365.8573

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and what is not working?

Comment: I was trying to make a stacked bar plot , the data not being displayed in stacks , while all the elements are being created the displaying of the stack plot is not working it only shows one output. I post the picture.

Comment: https://paste.pics/dff3a81e67cf670af31f756d1757c6e2 .                                                
this is the current output

Comment: i just changed the format of the csv file and it started to work , so please tell me just one thing is d3 highly dependent on the format of csv or i need more knowledge just to manipulate any csv according to my likings??

Comment: I usually convert the csv to json before working with it in JavaScript. There are a bunch of sites that do this for you, but I use this one: https://csvjson.com/csv2json. I've come across some formatting issues that could trip up the conversion(such as making sure each column has a header), but it works pretty well.